# TOP 10 RANK TEAM

Tags: laravel

I try to make a top 10 rank for rugby teams in my app.

So, I made a table `classement` which stores the results and points

In my table, I have a column `nm_position_classement` which stores the position in the rank. I don't know really how to achieve this. I'm a little bit confuse at this point.

Hope someone could help me.

Maybe I should do a variable with an array with 1,2,3,...,10 ?

Here a part of my controller :

```
        if ($resultat_domicile > $resultat_visiteur) {

            $classement_domicile->nm_position_classement = 1;

        } else {

            $classement_domicile->nm_position_classement = 0;

       }
```

Comment: you can get top 10 ranks from SQL query using Eloquent

Comment: yes but when i display the table i would like to have nm_position_classement : 1, 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 ...10

Comment: set the order by nm_position_classement ASC and limit 10

Comment: i try now !!!!!

Comment: As @VishalVarshney said, with single table it's simple query with `orderBy` and `limit`

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Solution by OP.*

When you want to rank your result with numbers on a table with a simple method just do:

```
    @php
    $rank = 1;
    @endphp

    @foreach($classements as $classement)
    <tr>
        <th>{{$rank++}}</th>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
DB::table('classement')->orderBy('nm_position_classement', 'ASC')->limit(10)->get();
```

Comment: working ! it's okay but the real question is what i did in the controller with the condition. normaly i will have to make something like  $classement_domicile->nm_position_classement = ++ ; ? you know what i mean ? actualy the query display and ordered by nb_points so the rank is correct but in terms of number positions i'm not good